# how to use create and open callback in Room database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

In the code, I got an instance from the Room.databaseBuilder, added a callback and lastly i built the database.
After a call to

```
this.mMovieDatabase =  
this.mMovieDBPersistentBuilder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
```

i expected the logs inside the callback to be called, but that did not happen. The logs inside the callback got called when the insertTuplePersistentDB() is called.

my questions:

1-why the callbacks has not been called

```
this.mMovieDatabase = 
this.mMovieDBPersistentBuilder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
```

when this line got executed??

2-what is the purpose of the db object provided in the callback, and how to use them??it contains methods like

```
.update()

.delete()

.execSql()
```

**code_1**:

```
 public void buildPersistentDB() {
    Log.v(TAG_LOG, "->buildPersistentDB");
    this.mMovieDBPersistentBuilder = Room
            .databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), 
 MovieDatabase.class, ActMain.DATA_BASE_NAME);

    this.mMovieDBPersistentBuilder.addCallback(new 
 RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);
            Log.w(TAG_LOG + "->onCreate", " buildPersistentDB->DB is 
 created, all tables has been created");
            Log.w(TAG_LOG + "->onCreate", " buildPersistentDB->DB 
 db.getPath(): " + db.getPath());
            Log.w(TAG_LOG + "->onCreate", " buildPersistentDB->DB  
 db.toString(): " + db.toString());
            Log.w(TAG_LOG + "->onCreate", " buildPersistentDB->DB 
 db.isOpen(): " + db.isOpen());
            Log.w(TAG_LOG + "->onCreate", " buildPersistentDB->DB 
 db.isReadOnly(): " + db.isReadOnly());
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpen(db);
            Log.w(TAG_LOG + "->onOpen", " 
 buildPersistentDB->onCreate\n");
            Log.w(TAG_LOG + "->onOpen", " buildPersistentDB->DB has been 
 opened");
        }
    });
    this.mMovieDatabase = 
 this.mMovieDBPersistentBuilder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
 }

 private void insertTuplePersistentDB(int recordNum) {
    Log.v(TAG_LOG, "->insertTuplePersistentDB is called. recodNum: " + 
 recordNum);

    Movie movie = new Movie();
    for (int i = 1; i <= recordNum; i++) {
        movie.setMovieId(String.valueOf(i));
        movie.setMovieName("Movie_episode_" + String.valueOf(i));
        mMovieDatabase.dao().insertOnlySingleMovie(movie);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1-why the callbacks has not been called

The **onCreate** callback would only be called once in the lifetime of the database i.e. when the file is opened.

- It allows you to do other things e.g. perhaps create a table or tables that is or are not covered by Room.

The **onOpen** callback will be called whenever the database has been opened (see below)

- It allows you to do things you may wish to do not covered by Room.

**Just building the database does not open the underlying SQLite database, it is not until you try to access the database, i.e. get, add, delete or update data that the database is opened and created if necessary.**

> 2-what is the purpose of the db object provided in the callback, and
>   how to use them??it contains methods like ....

**db** is an SupportSQLiteDatabase object and if using a callback you would likely want to do something not supported by Room (e.g. add this table not covered by room for whatever reason). To add a table you need to be able to run the SQL to CREATE the table and you then you'd use `db.execSQL(your_SQL_as_a_String);` and hence why the SupportSQLiteDatabase is passed.

In Room's terminology SupportSQLiteDatabase is :-

- > A database abstraction which removes the framework dependency and
  >   allows swapping underlying sql versions. It mimics the behavior of
  >   SQLiteDatabase.